# Configuring Jenkins build for Azure Function App targeting .NET Core 2.0

Tags: azure, jenkins, continuous-integration, .net-core, azure-functions

I am trying to setup a Jenkins build for an Azure Function App that targets .NET Core 2.0

One of the prerequisites is obviously to install the .NET Core SDK and runtime. I tried following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/using-ci-with-cli) and called the [dotnet-install.ps1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) but it fails with an error -

> dotnet-install: Downloading legacy link: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/--verbose/dotnet-dev-win-x86.--verbose.zip
>
> Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to download https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/--verbose/dotnet-dev-win-x86.--verbose.zip.
>   StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content:
>
> System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     x-ms-request-id: 34b62ce6-601e-00bb-7624-c5493f000000
>     x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
>     Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 17:01:18 GMT
>     Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0
>     Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>     Content-Length: 215
>     Content-Type: application/xml
>   }

Question is

- Is the dotnet-install.ps1 the recommended approach to install dotnet on the build agents? Is it even working or would installing it directly on the machine make more sense?
- Is there a similar PS script for .NET Core 2.0?
- Any best practices while setting up a Jenkins build for Azure Function App targetting .NET Core.

Comment: How exactly did you call `dotnet-install.ps1`. What exact error did it display? FWIW, that script should let you install 2.0 too. Did you check the help output of that script?

Comment: A 'Windows Powershell' step in the Build process. Just testing that script locally also fails with an error indicating that the sdk is not present at the location the script is trying to fetch it from